# Use app var in file required by app in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have following structure:

```
- build/
-- app.js
-- middlware/
--- authorization.js
-- model
--- Model1.js
--- Model2.js
-- routes
--- common.js
```

It's just beginning, and there will be more files. I just created an auth mechanism using passport and its working, but now I want to move it outside `app.js` file to `middleware/authorization.js`, and move my 'login' route to routes. When I do that I receive error

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
^
```

> ReferenceError: app is not defined

How can I refer to app in file, which is required in app?

My other question is that I intend to use mongoose models which are now also defined in `app.js` but will be placed in `model/*js`. Should I explicitly require necessary modules in each files, for example mongoose in `model/*.js`, then mongoose and model files in `middleware/authorization.js` or is there any magical way to just use all variables throughout whole app (not counting global variables)?

And my last question is, how can I import to `app.js` all other js files from `build/` and its subdirectories? Maybe I should just do that manually, every file in separate require?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject app into your authorization module. ex.

authorization.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(passport.initialize());
}
```

app.js

```
var authorization = require('./middleware/authorization')(app);
```